# I can't figure out how to put the logo and the navigation links on the same line

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/zaidzac95/pen/qBKWKep

I want to have navigation links and image in the same line.

This is what HTML of header looks like:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="header">
      <nav class="sub-header">
          <ul>    
             <li> <a href="">Home</a> </li>
             <li> <a href="">AboutUs</a> </li>
             <li> <a href="">Products</a> </li>
             <li> <a href="">Services</a> </li>
             <li> <a href="">Contact Us</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <img src="ethereum-eth-logo.png" class="logo">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the image like this(inside the nav tags):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:40px;">
  </a>
  ...
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` on your `.sub-header`. If your image is still not aligned, it's because of the padding you set. consider removing it or use other units of measure.

```css
.sub-header {
  display: inline-block;
  /* padding-left: 450px; */
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sub-header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">AboutUs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" class="logo">
```

Comment: Also you have to fix your code in the link you provided like `</a` or `<ahref="">`

Answer (score 0):

you have many typos in your code, and you should fix your HTML structure because it's very important. here is a rework for your code. you can check how things work in this code and then read more about them. good luck

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 200px;
    background: lightslategray;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo-container {
    background: lightcoral;
    width: 20%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo {
    height: 100px;
}

.nav-container {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list :nth-child(n) {
    /* nav children */
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav-list :nth-child(n):hover {
    /* nav children */
    color: white;
    background: lightslategray;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="header">

        <div class="logo-container">
          <img class="logo" src="ethereum-eth-logo.png">
        </div>
    
        <nav class="nav-container">
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li><a href="">Home</a</li>
            <li><a href="">AboutUs</a</li>
            <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

First clean-up your HTML!

HTML :

```
        <nav class="sub-header">
          <img src="../avatar_114.jpg" alt="ACME logo" class="logo">
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AboutUs</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

If You're not sure about the syntax, check it on https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea